# how many lines can be drawn from a point in space with n degrees of freedom?

Tags: geometry

[image: lines with equal alpha]

A friend of mine asked a very interesting, simple looking but very hard to answer question, due to lack of good mathematics knowledge *and* limited vocabulary I can't find the answer on Google!

How many (half) lines pass from a single point in 3 dimensional space, while each line (the vocab problem right here!) should have alpha degrees of freedom.

In 2D space it can be easily calculated:

```
360° / alpha° = n
```

Where **n** is the number of lines passing the point and **alpha** is degree of freedom?! assumed for each line.

edit: I added a picture, it's not good but you get the idea! thanks:)

Comment: The term "degree of freedom" in mathematics has a standard meaning which is different from how you are using it.

Comment: @vadim123 how should I mention 'distance of two lines starting from a single point in space'? distance is definitely wrong I know

Comment: Are you talking about roots of unity?

Comment: dear @PeterBrown, I don't think so, at least after reading wikipedia about roots of unity. I added a picture though. thank you.

Comment: You should google for "evenly distributed points on a sphere" and you'll find many more search-phrases…

Comment: @Dirk wow... such a lovely comment, found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere. maybe you should post it as an answer and then I accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is closely related to what is known as the [Tammes problem](http://www.uvm.edu/~pdodds/files/papers/others/1994/mooers1994a.pdf), which asks to distribute $n$ points on a sphere so as to maximize the minimum distance between any two points, $d_n$. Your problem is equivalent to finding the largest $n$ such that $d_n\le\alpha$.

Comment: very nice article! very nice! thank you.